# Router and Modem with the following capabilities

Tags: networking, router, modem

*I'm not sure whether this is the right StackExchange site to ask this question:*

I need an ADSL Modem + Router with the following capabilities:

1. IP based network filter for external networks.
2. IP based network filter for internal networks.
3. Monitor network traffic.
4. Compatible with WireShark.

I am a programmer and don't have network skills. Please suggest a product that has all the above mentioned features.

Comment: There isn't a 'right' [stackexchange site for shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) since such questions are ephemeral in nature. Considering your featureset though, i'd suggest running the modem and router seperately as the features you want are *not* consumer level features and most ADSL modem/routers lack those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those features, you'll need a professional router, such as a full-fledged Cisco router, or a Linux/FreeBSD/Unix-OS-of-choice box.  You're unlikely to find any of those features, and almost guaranteed not to find 2 or more, on any SOHO routers.  The only exception I can think of would be one of the Linksys WRT54G routers running the [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) third-party firmware, which basically turns it into a Linux router.  If that works for you great, but then a standard Linux router would work just as well for your purposes, too.  (The only advantage I know of to the WRT54G in this case is the handy small package).